# Spring multimodul project run classes

Tags: java, spring

I got two finished spring projects which should be connected to a multimodul-project.

This works fine with the spring modules and I get one war file.
But I don't know what to do with the main run classes from both projects. It works with one and both.

Do I need only one `SpringApplication.run` in the main module, or is one in both modules better?

**Main class:**

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = "com.test.multimodule")
public class App2 extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(App2.class, args);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you deploy your application as an WAR file you don't need a main-function. You only need a main function if you include an webserver in your application and start it as a JAR File from the command line with java -jar yourApp.jar.